# Division and Loops for Beginners

Tags: ruby, loops, recursion

Could someone help me figure this out how to do this in Ruby?

I have an array of integers. For each of those integers, I need to find a divisor that is two digits long (whole numbers as well). Right now, the code is looping to infinity. The answer I'm trying to get is:

```
int_a = 2, int_b = 11, and x = 22
```

Here is the code:

```
[22, 33].each do |x| 
  x.to_f
  int_a = 1
  int_b = x.quo(int_a)

     until int_a > 15 || int_b%2==0 && sprintf("%g", int_b).to_s.length == 2 
        puts "#{x}"
        puts "#{int_a}"
        puts "#{int_b}"  
     end  
  int_a += 1
 end
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following your code, but you at least need some of your variables to change inside your `until` block, or you'll never move closer to exiting it. Perhaps you intend the `int_a += 1` to be inside that `until` block?

Comment: will try.  I'm basically looking for two things, and I don't know how to simplify it. I'm taking the number 22, changing it to a float, and then dividing it by another number(that counts up) until the product is both a whole number and 2 digits long.

Comment: Changing the 'until' to the 'if' solved the loop problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your code, but by your definition:

For each of those integers, I need to find a divisor that is two digits long(whole numbers as well)

Give this a try:

```
numbers = [22,33]
numbers.map do |n|
  raise "invalid number" if n < 10
  div = 10.0
  div += 1 while (n%div) != 0
  div
end
#result: [11,22]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @fotanus, I can't understand your code, but answering your question, I used this code a while ago for finding divisors:

```
require 'prime'

def divisors_for(n)
  n.prime_division.map do |n,mp|
    (0..mp).map { |i| n**i }
  end.inject([1]) do |a, factor_group|
    a.product(factor_group)
  end.map do |factors|
    factors.flatten.reduce(:*)
  end - [n]
end

[22, 23].map do |n|
  divisors_for(n).select { |d| d.to_s.size == 2 }
end
```

Comment: thanks! i didn't know there was a prime_division method, this is super helpful also.